# Ninject mixed scopes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

Imagine that I have the following constructor injects with Ninject:

Service(A) -> Support(B) -> Repository (C)

A = Transient scope
B = Singleton scope
C = InRequest scope

What happens when the http request ends ?
Does Ninject dispose C thus having a dangling C instance as member in B ?

Comment: It's not a "dangling instance" per se.  It's a "disposed" but not Garbage collected instance, because Ninject will call Dispose (assuming C implements IDisposable) but the reference to the non-gc'd instance will remain, but it's state will be uncertain because its been disposed.

Comment: What you describe is a general problem called [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). A DI library will not magically solve this for you, although some DI libraries warn about these kinds of misconfigurations.

Comment: Steven, your link to the Captive Dependency article is exactly what I was looking for, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Ninject [documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) for `.InRequestScope()`

> Disposable instances are Disposed at end of request processing.

with the key word being Disposable.

If your Singleton is maintaining a strong reference to the injected `C` dependency, it would not be eligible to be garbage collected at the end of the Http request and would by extension be treated as a singleton itself, even though Ninject would still make an attempt to dispose of the instance at the end of the Http request, which, as Eric mentioned in the comments, may leave the object in an unreliable state.

This is probably a design smell and it would make sense to either break out the `C` dependency from the Singleton, or wholly incorporate it so that it's behavior is not unexpected.

Comment: Thx David, I was just curious what Ninject would do in this imaginary case ;-)

Comment: @PatrickPeters Fair enough, and an interesting dilemma :).  In this imaginary case, Ninject would LOVE to dispose of the C dependency, but the singleton won't allow it.

Comment: @DavidL - I think you're confusing Garbage collection with Disposal.  You can Dispose something without its reference being garbage collected.  If C implementes IDisposable, then Ninject *will* call Dispose on C at the end of the request, but the instance will still exist because there is a reference to it, but will be disposed so you can't really rely on its state.  Or maybe that's what you're saying, it's unclear to me.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, you're right, it wasn't clear.  I've updated my answer to reflect your comments.